# How to create gradient border on listview item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I would like to have a gradient border like bellow image:
This is the corner of a listview item:

[image]

The gray part is the backgorud, the white is the listview item. 
How do I create the gradient border effect?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a **9 patch** for the background of your View.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle"> 
 <gradient 
     android:startColor="#SomeGradientBeginColor"
     android:endColor="#SomeGradientEndColor" 
     android:angle="270"/> 

<corners 
     android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
 </shape>
```

Comment: how I set it in my listview?

Comment: try attributes background in xml

Answer (score 0):

These effects are achieved by 9patch images in android. There are some predefined for example `android.R.drawable.picture_frame`, however, you usually need to create your own.

The best way for your list item is using a [`CardView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) which allows you to set rounded corners and elevation and creates similar effect. There actually is [a tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) with `ListView` if had a look into the android documentation.